# N Tier layer - load details into object

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, n-tier-architecture

I created a website using the following structure:

**Class Project** - Called DataAccessLayer > Added a Dataset > Add a tableAdapter and Datatable with a query called GetcustomersByID(ID)

**Class Project** - Called BusinessLayer > Created some code to call into the DataAccessLayer and return the results in a CustomerDataTable for the query GetcustomersByID(ID)

**Web Project** - Added a reference to the BusinessLayer.

From this point i can add an ObjectDataSource and tie it to the Business Layer and call the appropriate method (in this example GetCustomersByID(ID)).

I then wanted to add an extra layer where i was hoping to load all customer data into a customer object. So i add another **class** called **Customers** and add all the fields as [B]properties [/B](CustomerID, FirstName, Surname, AddressOne etc).

How could i load all the details from the BusinessLayer into this object, so i could write code such as

```
Dim myCustomer as Customer
....
...... Some code to get the data and load it into the Customer object.

If myCustomer.Firstname = "Bob" Then
....
End If
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Do you want to map from a data access object to a business object?

Comment: What i would like to know is how i could load the Customer class with the result(s) returned so i could write some code to see if the customername is "Bob" OR how could i check if the customer name is Bob if i cant load the results into a class?

Comment: So, you have a data table and you want to map that to a class?

Comment: Yes - thats correct. A Datatable is returned when the Business layer method called GetcustomersByID(ID) is called

Answer (score 0):

In order to pull data out of your data table you can do the following:

```
Customer customer = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => 
        // construct and map all the properties
        new Customer
        {
            Id = row.Field<int>("Id"),
            Firstname = row.Field<string>("Name")
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

And in VB.NET something like this (although, I'm not a VB guy):

```
Dim customer As Customer = dt.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(row) New Customer() With     { _
    Key .Id = row.Field(Of Integer)("Id"), _
    Key .Firstname = row.Field(Of String)("Name") _
}).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont know how well you want this app to scale but you might want to consider looking into the Active Record pattern or the Domain Model pattern for help on deciding how to structure your layers.

Instead of populating Data Tables you could use DTO or POCO objects and populate the data straight into them with an ORM like Dapper.NET. And then you can use AutoMapper to populate your business objects from the DTO's.

If you go Active Record you could just have your business objects call the data directly and populate themselves.

You can do a zillion different things.

Also you probably dont want your front end to make calls to a service layer or facade layer instead of directly to your business logic.

Or better yet drop the relational data source and use a Document database like RavenDB or Mongo and remove the redundant layer calls all together. Store flexible objects of data instead of rigid rows. Then you will find populating your business objects will be a no brainer.

Comment: Are there any examples of using the DTO approach? Or even if you could provide me with an example?

Comment: A Data Transfer Object is just an object wich holds data and has no logic. It should have properties to hold the data thats all. Take a look at Dapper and go over the simple tutorial. And you will see how to call the database and then map the data to your DTO object. https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net